# django connecting twice to database

Tags: python, mysql, django

I made a very simple app in django in which I have one model, when a request comes, I basically filter objects from that model and then render them in the template. It seems to be working fine, but when I went to check my database logs. I found out that django connect twice on every request to retrieve information about the request session. Any one can help me with why this is happening? see below is the example log

```
110414 18:28:29     8 Connect   root@localhost on project1_dev
            8 Query SET NAMES utf8
            8 Query set autocommit=0
            8 Query SELECT `django_session`.`session_key`, `django_session`.`session_data`, `django_session`.`expire_date` FROM `django_session` WHERE (`django_session`.`session_key` = '7af6952f847471091a83ee9382bb858d'  AND `django_session`.`expire_date` > '2011-04-14 10:28:29' )
            8 Query SELECT `category_main`.`id`, `category_main`.`slug`, `category_main`.`is_active`, `category_main`.`site_id`, `django_site`.`id`, `django_site`.`domain`, `django_site`.`name` FROM `category_main` INNER JOIN `category_main_i18n` ON (`category_main`.`id` = `category_main_i18n`.`main_id`) INNER JOIN `django_site` ON (`category_main`.`site_id` = `django_site`.`id`) WHERE (`category_main_i18n`.`language` = 'en'  AND `category_main`.`is_active` = 1 )
            8 Quit  
            9 Connect   root@localhost on project1_dev
            9 Query SET NAMES utf8
            9 Query set autocommit=0
            9 Query SELECT `django_session`.`session_key`, `django_session`.`session_data`, `django_session`.`expire_date` FROM `django_session` WHERE (`django_session`.`session_key` = '7af6952f847471091a83ee9382bb858d'  AND `django_session`.`expire_date` > '2011-04-14 10:28:29' )
            9 Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you, by any chance, serving your media files using django ? that would create additional requests and thus additional query.

The "session" query is done on every request, that's why I think you may be doing more requests than you think.

Comment: Yes am using django to serve files. But I did a quick thing, I just turned debug mode to false because its conditionally including the url if debug is true. I also removed all the other tags that serve any css or js and kept a simple for loop to print the query and still am seeing the same result from above.  Its querying the database twice and the weird part, its closing the connection and opening again.

Comment: You could try using django debug toolbar to keep track of your SQL requests, it might give you a little more intel to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the exact same thing. In my case it turned out it was a request for favicon that was the cause. It did not show up in the Chrome network console, nor in the access log from manage.py. I solved it by simply adding a facicon.ico for my site.

I also tried the debug toolbar, but the SQL queries did not turn up there, probably because they where not associated with a view.